# sensors-detect not detecting my fan

Tags: configuration, intel

sensors-detect detects my system perfectly:

```
# sensors-detect revision 6209 (2014-01-14 22:51:58 +0100)
# System: Acer Aspire E1-572 [V2.14] (laptop)
# Board: Acer EA50_HW
```

It detects an Intel digital thermal sensor (driver coretemp).

But when I run `sensors` it does not show any fan, so when I run pwmconfig it says `There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed.`

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +46.0 C  (high = +100.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
Core 0:         +46.0 C  (high = +100.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
Core 1:         +43.0 C  (high = +100.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
```

The problem is, this fan is turning on and off even and it's noise is disturbing me. So I want to configure it better.

If no one can help me I might just end up disconecting the fan from the motherboard.

Comment: Have you looked if there are BIOS settings to control the fan? I haven't played with this for a while myself, IIRC on one of my motherboards it depended on where the FAN was connected (CPU/case) if it would show up. But on a laptop there is little chance of changing the hardware connection, so BIOS settings might be your best option.

Comment: there is no bios fan control settings unfortunatelly