# HP ProLiant Server with centOS no fans detected

Tags: centos, fan

I tried to find a solution but this whole situation drives me crazy, especially with a server next to with three fans and all run on max with no obvious reason. He seems to have the same problem [sensors-detect not detecting my fan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157178/sensors-detect-not-detecting-my-fan).

I have a HP ProLiant server with a quad core CPU and centOS. I did the following steps:

1. `sudo yum install lm_sensors`
2. `sudo sensors-detect` and confirmed everything with yes
3. `sensors`

Output of `sensors`

`acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:         +8.3°C  (crit = +31.3°C)`

Here you can already see that something is wrong. Why do I just see one temperature and nothing else? Shouldn't there be the fans and the temperature of the other CPUs?

5. `sudo pwmconfig`

Output 
`/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`

I tried to install fancontrol with `sudo yum install fancontrol` but this package does not exist.

6. `sudo fancontrol`

Output `Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...
Error: Can't read configuration file`

7. In the BIOS I did not find anything to control the fan speed, like disable fans always on or something. Maybe that is also a way?

I have literally no idea what to do and any help is highly appreciated. Please note, that I am new to this and please tell me about assumptions you made and how to install any required packages. As a beginner it is super frustrating if anybody says do this and that but does not tell where the file is or how to get it.

Please let me know when you need any further information.
Regards,
René

Comment: Which ProLiant do you have? (It's a range, not a model.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Unix & Linux StackExchange!

HP uses a proprietary fan controller system in their servers, that is not supported by `lm-sensors` at all. In some models, the fan control is partially relegated to software, with a hardware failsafe: if the appropriate drivers are not communicating with the fan control hardware, the fans will go to full speed and stay that way until the drivers are installed and running.

In 2015, the Hewlett-Packard company was split in two: the enterprise IT unit became HPE (Hewlett-Packard Enterprise), and consumer-grade hardware was left under the main HP brand. ProLiant servers and their support are now provided by HPE, even if the server was originally sold under the main HP brand.

You should go to https://www.hpe.com and select Support -> Support Center. In there, you can type in your server model to a search field (e.g. "ProLiant DL380 G7), and get to a page where you can select the exact model you have (in case the model name you specified was ambiguous), the operating system you're using, and that you're looking for downloads.

(You can get the exact model name with `dmidecode -s system-product-name`.)

For CentOS, you can probably use the driver packages intended for the corresponding version of RedHat Enterprise Linux. Different models can have different driver sets, so without knowing your exact model, I cannot give more detailed instructions. But once you get the appropriate drivers up and running, you will usually immediately hear the difference in fan behavior with no configuration needed.

Also, if your server is a rack-mount model, be aware that they are designed to pack the maximum amount of computing power to a unit of space, in an air-conditioned server room, not to be easy on the ears.

---

On [the question you linked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157178/sensors-detect-not-detecting-my-fan), the problem may be the same, but the underlying cause is likely to be very different: on laptops, the fans are typically controlled by the ACPI firmware. Through the kernel's ACPI features, you might be able to force the fans *on*, but there is usually no way to prevent laptop fans from running, as without them the system might quickly overheat and be damaged if the processor runs at full speed for any significant length of time - and as a laptop typically contains a lithium-ion battery, overheating it can cause a real risk of fire.

Usually the only way to stop a laptop with Linux from running its fans is to use the `cpufreq`/`cpupower` commands to restrict the maximum CPU clock speed low enough so that the fans won't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of telcoM I solved the problem. I hope this small guide will help others.

1. Find out the exact server model `dmidecode -s system-product-name`
2. Go to https://www.hpe.com and select Support -> Support Center
3. Search for your server
4. Find the `System Health Application` (I took this one [HPE System Health Application and Command Line Utilities for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_354a269ee7a84cfdb2d227dbcb#tab1)
5. Install it on your server. See installation instruction in the support center. It is something like this `rpm –qp –requires hp-health-<version>.rpm`
6. Reboot the server
7. Check fan speeds on the server with `sudo hpasmcli` and then `show fans`
8. Enjoy a more quit server